# How can I show the button only in parent element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a little question. I have a nested table. The first item in this table should be removed. Everything is okay so far. But how can I show the 'Remove User' button only on the first elements?

```js
class UserList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      openDetail: false
    }
  }

  parentUserToggle (item, index) {
    this.setState({
      openDetail: !this.state.openDetail
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { userProfile, index } = this.props;
    let parentUserItem = null;
    if (userProfile.children instanceof Object) {
      parentUserItem = userProfile.children.map((children, index) => {
        return <UserList key={children.ID} index={index} userProfile={children} />
      });
    }
    return (
      <div className="table-row" key={index}>
        <div className="col-md-1">
          {
            userProfile.children ?
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={this.parentUserToggle.bind(this, userProfile.children)}
            >
              { !this.state.openDetail ? 'OPEN' : 'CLOSE' }
            </button>
            : null
          }
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-3">{userProfile.Name}</div>
        <div className="col-md-3">{userProfile.City}</div>
        <div className="col-md-3">{userProfile.Phone}</div>
        <div className="col-md-2">
          {
            userProfile || !parentUserItem ?
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger"
              onClick={this.props.removeUser}
            > Remove User </button>
            : null
          }
        </div>
        <div className={this.state.openDetail ? 'table-true' : 'table-false'}>
          {
            parentUserItem
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for support.

Comment: Your code not working

Comment: You can use the index to check whether that's the first element. If the index is 0, you can enable the remove button.

Comment: yes is this snippet not full of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I answered a little late. But the problem I solved that day. The correct answer was to check with props. Thank you for your support!

```js
{
  this.props.removeUser ?
  <button
    className="btn btn-danger"
    onClick={this.props.removeUser}
  > Remove User </button>
  : null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the value of `index` that you're passing as `key` is an incremental numerical value starting from 1, you can do:

```
onClick={Number(index) === 1 ? this.props.removeUser : null}
```

Or, depends on what you're trying to do, but hopefully this will serve you well

```
      {
        userProfile || !parentUserItem || Number(index) === 1 ?
        <button
          className="btn btn-danger"
          onClick={this.props.removeUser}
        > Remove User </button>
        : null
      }
```

Comment: I do not know why it was voted down. But that's not what I want. I want the Remove User button to be rendered only in the main array. Do not be a render once you're inside a child. Would you please examine the Remove User button?

Comment: if you explain what's the `main` array I can give you the answer, but with what I've shared should be enough for you to solve afaik

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/jv7bK this is my array. I turn around with map in this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your index is the prop of your index... (sounds obviously but not until you pass for us your parent component to check)

```
 {
    parseInt(index) === 0 || userProfile || !parentUserItem ||  ?
    <button
      className="btn btn-danger"
      onClick={this.props.removeUser}
    > Remove User </button>
    : null
  }
```

After your detailed explanation about the the problem :

```
{ Object.keys(userData).map((key, index) => {
  return(
    key === 0 ?
   <UserList key={key} index={index} userProfile={userData[key]} removeUser=
   {this.userDeleteToggle.bind(this, key)} removeUserButton={true}  />  :
   <UserList key={key} index={index} userProfile={userData[key]} removeUser=
   {this.userDeleteToggle.bind(this, key)}  removeUserButton={false} /> ); }) 
}
```

Now use the `removeUserButton` as prop inside your child component, if true not render the button.

I have to go now, i hope it works, I'll check your answer later.

Comment: This is my array imgur.com/a/jv7bK I just want the remove button in the first element in the array. There is no remove button in the children in the Array because the remove button does not work for children.

Comment: please provide your parent component also.

Comment: `{
                    Object.keys(userData).map((key, index) => {
                      return(
                        <UserList
                          key={key}
                          index={index}
                          userProfile={userData[key]}
                          removeUser={this.userDeleteToggle.bind(this, key)}
                        />
                      );
                    })
                  }`